# ReSharper rule to indent attribute tags in C#?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

I'm working in a large set of code with lots of attribute tags, many containing paragraphs.  This makes it difficult to read the code.  I was trying to figure out if there's a way to add an extra indentation to any line with an attribute tag and also (maybe) add a return between attributes and code.  I'm new to ReSharper and have been unable to find this information on my own (attribute tags don't seem to be something normally formatted specially for?)

```
    //now
    [vEditorToolbar("Test", order = 0)]
    [SerializeField] [vReadOnly] protected bool _isTest;
    [vBarDisplay("maxTest")] [SerializeField] protected float _currentTest;
    public bool isExample = false;
    [vHelpBox("If you.... has a value greater zero")]

    //preferred
        [vEditorToolbar("Test", order = 0)]
        [SerializeField] [vReadOnly] 
    protected bool _isTest;
        [vBarDisplay("maxTest")] [SerializeField] 
    protected float _currentTest;
    public bool isExample = false;
        [vHelpBox("If you.... has a value greater zero")]
```